# efficiently convert words to vectors using bert

Tags: google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am trying to convert reviews Text to vectors using bert. I am using pretrained bert from tensorflowhub. While encoding it on TPU on google colab it crashes the memory.I have seen some articles most of the people are defining bert layers for creating embedings.
My code is file is:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hfV1V9aMKIfWruH59H6xCCqNxwX6amub?usp=sharing

I am currently passing 400 reviews and creating there embedings then storing them to a seperate file but this is a very long work

Any sort of help would be appreciated

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert

Comment: hi i dont want to use bert for classification purpose. I just want to generate wordembedings from it